# stem extension of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question about the relation between the double cover of group and the stem extension. Is there any one could give the definition of both of them and the relation between them?

Answer (score 2):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_multiplier

A stem extension is a short exact sequence of groups $1 \to Z \to E \to G \to 1$, with $Z \le Z(E) \cap [E,E]$.

When people refer to a double cover, they usually mean a stem extension with $|Z|=2$.